# How to set the APK file name specific to both flavor AND build type?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-productflavors

For Gradle in Android Studio:
there are many posts explaining how to set the APK file name based on the build type.  I don't recall if I found any explaining how to do it based on the flavor. There are none explaining how to do it based on both.

I have 6 flavors and of course, 2 build types (debug & release).  I need to specify a different APK file name for release only, for each flavor.

The normal default APK file name should be used for all debug builds.

So if my flavors are A, B, C, D, E and F; then only when I build a release build, do I want the APK files to be A.apk, B.apk, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have written this piece of code and it helps in building the apk names as you requested. Note it is inside the "android" element, as a sibling of "buildTypes" and "productFlavors":

```
android {
    ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
        }
        debug {
            ...
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        A {
            ...
        }
        B {
            ...
        }
        C {
            ...
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def buildType = variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.buildType.name

        if (buildType == android.buildTypes.release.name) {
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def flavour = variant.productFlavors[0].name
                def newName = flavour + ".apk"
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I define the variables:

- **buildType:** name of the buildType you have selected in the Build Variant tab.
- **flavor:** name of the flavor you have selected in the Build Variant tab.

The "if" condition checks that you are building the buildType "release", so the apk name only changes in this case.